# magento 2 Required PHP extension 'Imagick' was not loaded

Tags: magento2, php

I get this error when **upgrading my back up Magento 2**.

How I can fix this error ? and which module need Imagick ?

My server's OS is CentOS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the PHP imagick module on your server, for CentOS you should be able to use:

```
sudo yum install php-imagick
```

To install the module.

If that doesn't work, you can follow: https://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/install-imagemagick-php-imagick-centos/

Installing on CentOS 6: https://www.vultr.com/docs/install-imagemagick-on-centos-6

Comment: No package php-imagick available.

Comment: Edited my answer. You can also try `sudo yum install php7-imagick` (Depends on your PHP version)

Comment: No package php7-imagick available.
i don't know why i get this error

Comment: Have you tried using the tutorial link in my answer?

Comment: i am trying ... and same error ...

Comment: What version of CentOS and PHP are you running on the server?

Comment: centos 6 and PHP 7.0.21

Comment: Might be worth following - https://www.vultr.com/docs/install-imagemagick-on-centos-6 for CentOS 6.